# How do I specify the order in which a column is indexed in Doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, indexing

The doctrine documentation gives the following example to create an index:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",indexes={@Index(name="search_idx", columns={"name", "email"})})
 */
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```

Is it possible the specify the order of each column in the index ?
For example, suppose that I want to specify that the name column to be indexed in DESC ordering.

Comment: Nope.  sql itself does not allow specifying the order when creating an index.

Comment: You're mistaken, I'm working on Oracle 11g and you can specify the order. Look for "ASC" or "DESC" on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm

Comment: I stand chastised.  I assume you tried columns={"name DESC", "email ASC"}?

Comment: MySQL does support that, too (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html).

Comment: MariaDB also supports it since version 10.8 (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13756)